# Cycle through elements of a relative timestamp and increment or decrement values

Tags: emacs, increment, decrement

In Emacs, how can I create a command that will cycle through the elements of the relative timestamp entry to increment or decrement its value.

For example:

01:20:12 :: Some text

1. When anywhere on the line, a keybinding will cycle through hh, mm, ss
2. A second keybinding to increment or decrement the numbers keeping the padded zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use library [DoReMi](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DoReMi) to easily create commands that increment/decrement something using the arrow keys (for example).

All you need is [`doremi.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/doremi.el), but [`doremi-mac.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/doremi-mac.el) can also be helpful to define DoReMi commands and add them to menus.

Comment: Wow. Thats a lot of Emacs power. Thanks.

Comment: For Incrementing & Decrementing, Found https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IncrementNumber

Answer (score 0):

I use `evil-numbers` for this, along with `easy-repeat`.  (`evil-numbers` is completely independent of `evil`.)  Apologies if you don't use `use-package`.  This doesn't help with your first question.

```
(use-package evil-numbers
  :config
  (easy-repeat-add 'evil-numbers/inc-at-pt 'evil-numbers/dec-at-pt)

  :bind (("C-c =" . evil-numbers/inc-at-pt)
         ("C-c -" . evil-numbers/dec-at-pt))
  )

(use-package easy-repeat
  :defer 1
  :config
  (defun easy-repeat-add (&rest commands)
    "Add COMMANDS to `easy-repeat-command-list'."
    (dolist (f commands)
      (add-to-list 'easy-repeat-command-list f))
    (easy-repeat-mode +1))

  (easy-repeat-add 'help-go-back 'help-go-forward
                   'next-buffer 'previous-buffer)

  (easy-repeat-mode 1)
  )
```